# What does the :: mean in C++?

Tags: c++, methods

```
void weight_data::rev_seq(string &seq){ 
//TODO
std::reverse(seq.begin(), seq.end());
}
```

In this C++ method, I think this method does not return anything, so the prefix is `void`, what does `::` tell the relationships between `weight_data` and `rev_seq(string &seq)`? Thanks!

Comment: :: is called Paamayim Nekudotayim in PHP.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`void` is the return type. `::` is the scope resolution operator, so it means `rev_seq` is inside the scope of `weight_data`. `weight_data` could be either a namespace or a class (based on what you've given, it's not possible to say which).

Comment: "weight_data" is defined as a struct in a a.hpp file with a method called "rev_seq" (not implemented), then in a.cpp file, this method is called as what I asked in the question part

Comment: @ladyfafa: `void weight_data::rev_seq(string &seq) {...}` __is__ the implementation of that member function.

Comment: @sbi: Okay, i see; can it be implemented more than once? i.e. in different cpp files, to make different implementations of the same function "rev_seq" that is from the struct "weight_data"

Comment: @ladyfafa: no -- C++ has a "one definition rule" (ODR) that says any one function can only be implemented (defined) once. There are a few sort of exceptions (e.g., for inline functions) but they're only sort of exceptions, and this wouldn't fit any of them anyway.

Comment: @ladyfafa: Generally, definitions must appear only once. (See [What is the difference between a definition and a declaration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration/1410632#1410632)) However, different member functions could be implemented in different implementation files. Also, conditional compilation could be used to include one of several definitions of the same entity depending on some preconditions (e.g, the platform for which a program is compiled).

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: thanks! I basically see, if i remember correctly, seems java interfaces can be implemented more than once?

Comment: @ladyfafa: That's something else entirely. The equivalent to Java's interfaces in C++ would be abstract classes (classes which contain at least one pure virtual member function). As in Java, in C++ you can derive several classes from such an abstract base class, each implementing the interface in a different way. __Function definitions__, however, must only ever occur once in a program. I'm sure that's the same in Java.

Comment: @sbi: right. thanks. So, in my question post, after the implemenation of the function "rev_seq", there is no further neccesity of stating that "rev_seq" is of struct "weight_data", I mean, this function could be called anywhereelse freely?

Comment: As @sbi already pointed out, a Java interface is kind of like a class that can only declare virtual functions, not (for example) any data, nor can it implement any of the functions. In that case, the "implements" is a bit more abstract.

Comment: @ladyfafa: unless it's a static function, you have to invoke it as a member of an objects, like: `weight_data w; w.rev_seq(whatever);`

Comment: So java interface is a class with methods that only have declaration but no implementation, if a class is going to implement this interface, then the methods in this class can be implemented in different ways, right?

Comment: @ladyfafa: Please go and read [What is the difference between a definition and a declaration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/1410632#1410632) Basically, the compiler needs a __declaration__ of a function for you to be able to call it. The linker needs one, and only one, __definition__ of it. Class members are declared in their class' definition. They can be defined within their class' definition or outside of it. (If thy are defined within, they are implicitly `inline`. Inlined functions can be defined more than once, provided the definitions are exactly equal.)

Comment: @sbi: I read through the post, very good examples

Comment: @ladyfafa: When you derive from an abstract class (`A`), you define a new class (`B`): `class B : public A {...};` When, in this new class, you implement one of the base class' pure virtual functions (`A::f()`), you are not redefining the abstract base class' member. Instead you define a member function of the derivded class (`B::f()`) to stand in for the abstract base class' pure virtual (`A::f()`).

Comment: @ladyfafa: You might want to pick up a basic C++ introduction. Have a look at [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: "std::reverse(seq.begin(), seq.end());"  will reverse the string "seq", right?

Comment: @ladyfafa: As you'll likely will have found out by now, it does.

Answer (score 15):

In C++,

- *`A::B`* means `B` is an identifier within either `namespace` or `class` type `A`,
- *`A.B`* means `B` is a member of the `struct`, `class`, or `union` type an instance of which is referred to by the object or reference `A`, and
- *`A->B`* means `B` is a member of the `struct`, `class`, or `union` type an instance of which is referred to by the pointer `A`. (It's equivalent to `(*A).B`.)

In some other languages, all three cases are covered by a `.` only.

Note that in C++, member function don't have to be implemented (defined) within their class' definition. (If they are, they are implicitly `inline`.) They can be, and often are, implemented in separate implementation (`.cpp`) files. This has the advantage that not all users of a class need to recompile when you change an implementation of one of the class' member functions. So unless `weight_data` is a `namespace` name, `void weight_data::rev_seq(string &seq) {...}` is such a definition of a class member outside of its class.

Comment: that was very comprehensive, many thanks!

Comment: Note: The `*` and `->` operators can be overloaded.  Usually they are only overloaded for things like iterators and smart pointers.  It is possible that poorly designed code will overload these operators.

Comment: @Brian: That's a very good point!

Answer (score 2):

`weight_data` is a [namespace](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/namespaces/) or class name.

Answer (score 0):

The line `void weight_data::rev_seq(string &seq)` tells the compiler that this is the definition of the `rev_seq(string &seq)` member function from the `weight_data`. If this just said `void rev_seq(string &seq) { ... }` the compiler would think that a non-member function was being defined, as opposed to the `rev_seq(string &seq)` member function of the `weight_data` class.

```
class weight_data
{
    void rev_str(string &seq);
}
```

It can also mean that `rev_str` refers to a function that is part of namespace `weight_data`.

```
namespace weight_data
{
    void rev_str(string &seq);
}
```

Comment: Note that `weight_data` might be a namespace. Also, I think you meant to write "If this just said `void rev_seq(string &seq) { ... }`...".

Comment: Thanks sbi for bringing this to my notice.

Answer (score 0):

Just thought of adding 2 more interesting things about the ::

a) Operator :: is both a unary and a binary operator

```
struct A{
   int m;
};

int x;
int main(){
   ::x;                     // Unary
   int (A::*p) = &A::m;     // Binary
}
```

b) $10.3/12 - "Explicit qualification with the scope operator (5.1) suppresses the virtual call mechanism."

```
struct A{
   virtual void f(){cout << 1;}
};

struct B : A{
   void f(){cout << 2;}
};

int x;
int main(){
   B b;
   A &ra = b;
   ra.f();     // dynamic binding, prints 2
   ra.A::f();  // suppress VF mechanism, prints 1.
}
```