# C++: Creating String

Tags: c++, string

I'm fairly new to C++ and I'm currently learning about strings.

So, I'm familiar with this way of creating a string from Java:

```
string text = "hello";
```

Now, I see something like:

```
 std::string text("hello");
```

So, the second one looks kind of difficult to read because I didn't know what the :: meant.

1. Why are there two ways to build strings?
2. What are the differences between them?
3. What situations would let me prefer to use one way rather the than the other?

Comment: `So, I'm familiar with this way of creating a string from Java:`  Pretend Java doesn't exist.  What you're asking are basic C++ questions that can be answered by most introductory books on C++.

Comment: I have no idea where you saw that second line, but there is nothing named `std::str` in standard C++.

Comment: `string text = "hello";` this is not java this is c++.  ` std::str("hello");`where did you see this?  Look in a book.

Comment: `::` is just the namespace separator token in C++.  It is similar to how you separate package/type names in Java with `.`.

Comment: It's been a long time since I programmed in Java, but I'm pretty sure it had the *assignment operator* and *constructors*, just like you see here.

Comment: This is actually two questions (at least). I've marked it as a duplicate of the question which is about the different methods of initialization. That post doesn't answer the part about the double colon though. That is a much simpler problem and is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480320/what-does-the-mean-in-c